# Setting up Miracast on Windows 8.1 / Samsung Smart TV UE65F6470SS

Tags: windows-8.1, miracast, smart-tv

I try since a few days to setup Miracast on my Desktop PC / Smart TV, which refuse to work.

(Cant use more than 2 links :-(..)

My Setup :

Samsung Smart TV UE65F6470SS

LAN using Router [FritzBox 7360](http://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-7360/)
OR 
WLAN using an "[Fritz!Wlan STick N v2](http://en.avm.de/service/fritzwlan/fritzwlan-stick-n-v2/overview/)"

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 5/6/2015, 13:04:55
       Machine name: DESKTOP
   Operating System: Windows 8.1 64-bit (6.3, Build 9600) (9600.winblue_r9.150322-1500)
           Language: German (Regional Setting: German)
System Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       System Model: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
               BIOS: BIOS Date: 12/17/14 20:14:40 Ver: 04.06.05
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz (8 CPUs), ~4.0GHz
             Memory: 16384MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 16342MB RAM
          Page File: 2588MB used, 17849MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.03.9600.17415 64bit Unicode

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980
       Manufacturer: NVIDIA
          Chip type: GeForce GTX 980
           DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
        Device Type: Full Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13C0&SUBSYS_13C01569&REV_A1
     Display Memory: 12111 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 3940 MB
      Shared Memory: 8170 MB
```

Windows PowerShell

```
PS C:\Users\Mirko> get-netadapter | select name, ndisversion

name                      NdisVersion
----                      -----------
WiFi                      6.40
Ethernet                  6.30

PS C:\Users\Mirko>
```

The PC is connected to 2 Samsung LED Monitors

Going into the PC-Settings->Devices my Samsung Smart TV is shown together with my WDTV Live.

If i go into the charm menu on the right side, and then choosing devices->project i should (according to the internet :-) ) see the choice to connect to the smart Tv, after choosing "Screen Mirroring" on my TV (I saw an youtube video where it worked with an Laptop and an Samsung Smart TV, exact this way).

But i only get the option to split/seperate the desktop with my 2 connected Samsung monitors.

I am not sure what i do wrong, because everything *should* support Miracast, but something dont.

Is anyone able to bring some light in this? I will provide more information if needed :-)

Comment: Is the TV Miracast certified? As a starting point I'd recommend you read all the relevant articles on [this blog](http://digitalmediaphile.com/index.php/tag/miracast/).

Comment: Hello Karan. Thank you for your Answer. Took me a few days to make some things sure. I have now an Microsoft Display Adapter Connected and working on my TV now (Saying Ready to connect). I just dont have this "add a wireless display" on my charm menu on the right side, after clicking project. I did ready the link you gave to me, Did just change nothing. Windows 8.1 / Wireless Network / and the wireless display adapter on my TV should do the job, but it dont.

Comment: Have you tried to [Add a device](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hvCq5.png) from *PC and devices*?

Comment: Hello. Yes, and my Tv is shown there. Could it be, that the problem is, that my pc is connected to two monitors ? will try and disconnect one monitor tomorrow.